# Order of "Edit Survey" questions vs report order?

Tags: surveymonkey

Take Survey_62495254 as an example.
The order in the survey editor is

```
Q1 is a type 80, 
Q2,Q3 are yes/no
Q4 is another type 80
etc
```

But in the results the order of PageID and QuestionID is

```
QuestionID   PageID   Pos   what Q it corresponds to
776900542   196014507   1   Q2
776900543   196014508   1   Q8
776900544   196014508   2   Q9
776900547   196014509   1   Q3
776900546   196014509   2   Q1
776900548   196014510   1   Q4
```

which is not the same.
So, how can I discover from the API download what the order of questions is?

Ta
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of questions is exposed by `get_survey_details`. Each question belongs to a page and each question on a page has a position. With these two data points, you can determine the overall order of the questions in the survey.

Comment: In the example I gave, the order of page and position is not the same as the order in the survey editor.  My question is: how can I determine via  the api what is seen in the editor? Ie q1 q2 q3 etc

Comment: This is asked by the client who finds it hard to match up in non-English surveys, the order of questions as reported by my app using the API, and the order reported by Surveymonkey as Q1,Q2, etc.

If it cannot be done, may I ask for an enhancement to the API:
Add to the Response Fields
`
    Name: data.pages[_].questions[_].Q    or maybe QOrder
    Description: returns Question order as seen by survey editor
    Return Type: Integer
`

so in my example the question in position 2 of the third page would return "QOrder"=1  because it is Q1 in the editor.

Comment: I'm confused by your reasoning. Page ID 196014510 has a position of "1" and question ID 776900548 has a position of 1 on it making it the first question in the survey and Q1 (not Q4 as in the question).

Page ID 196014508 has a position of 5 (page 5). Question ID 776900543 has a position of 1 on that page and is Q8 in the survey as you mentioned. If you count all the questions in the pages leading up to 776900543, it's the eighth question. 

776900546 is position 2 on a page with position 3. Pages 1 & 2 each have one question. 776900546 is Q4. It all lines up with the UI.

Comment: I see that now in the JSON.
"page_id":"196014510","position":1,"heading":"Task Users"}
I was not aware of the existence of that field "position" because it is not defined in https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_details
which only defines "position" for questions and answers. I had been assuming the page order was that of the page_id order. OK, that tells me what I need to know.
Thanks, Tony.